# Change the style by choosing the category of each article (Wordpress)

Tags: wordpress, elementor

I have 3 Post categories and I want to change the background color of Post content (one of the items in Elementor) by selecting each of the categories (for post). I want to do this through the function.php file.

```
If category (RED Cat) is selected, the background color will be red

If category (GREEN Cat) is selected, the background color will be green

If category (BLUE Cat) is selected, the background color will be blue
```

**If the new post to be added is in the (RED Cat) category, the background of the Post content will be red**

**If the new post to be added is in the category (BLUE Cat), the background of the Post content will be blue
And...**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution 1:**

You can add something like the below code to your `functions.php` file:

```php
function change_background_color_in_single() {
    If ( ! is_single() ) {
        return;
    }
    $categories       = get_the_category();
    if (!isset($categories[0])) {
        return;
    }
    $background_color = match ($categories[0]->name) {
        'Red' => 'red',
        'Yellow' => 'yellow',
        'Green' => 'green',
        default => 'white'
    };
    if ( ! $background_color ) {
        return;
    }
    echo '<style>
        .single-post {
            background-color: ' . $background_color . ';
        }
    </style>';
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'change_background_color_in_single' );
```

First, we check if we're on a single post page. Then, we check if a category exists. Finally, with a match expression, we can determine the color of the background. If you have a custom field for the color of categories, you can use the custom field's value.

Note that match expression is available for PHP 8 or later, and in lower versions, you need to use either switch case or if.

**Solution 2:**

Here's another way which checks if post has category:

`functions.php`:

```php
<?php

function change_background_color_in_single()
{
    $post = get_post();

    if (has_term('red', 'category', $post)) {
        echo '<style>.single-post { background-color: red; }</style>';
    }

    if (has_term('green', 'category', $post)) {
        echo '<style>.single-post { background-color: green; }</style>';
    }

    if (has_term('Yellow', 'category', $post)) {
        echo '<style>.single-post { background-color: yellow; }</style>';
    }
}

add_action('wp_head', 'change_background_color_in_single');
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply,
I use Solution 1 because I don't intend to edit any other file except the function, but even though I put the categories, it still takes the default value.

Comment: First and foremost, it depends on your theme. 
You must find the background class of your theme that you want to change its background color and change the CSS class. for example, in the latest WordPress with the default theme, `.signle-post` is the container of the whole page. I forgot to mention second solution also must be written in `functions.php`.

Comment: Solution 2 worked correctly and perfectly,
Thank you